# Easiest way to build a VPN Server for up to 50 concurrent clients

Tags: router, vpn, ssl-vpn

I have a local database running on a tower server with windows server 2012 for an organization, now I'm planning to make it run online for remote access, but I don't like to use public IP or host name for remote accessing
I want to create a VPN server that will enable my clients to connect to my database only when they connect to my VPN server.

My question is that what's the easiest way to do that, I heard about Cisco ASA 5505 and buying concurrent user license for Cisco anyconnect, I also heard about some vpn routers like the Netgear fvg318.

Please give me a details about this thing also the prices should not exceed $2000.

Comment: Are there any requirements beside “It has to be VPN”? Like IPSec, no client software required or whatever?

Comment: no it has not to be VPN but I think it's best to be VPN, and client software is required because the clients won't be on the same place everytime

Comment: Every modern operating system has built-in VPN clients (well, except Linux perhaps), but they differ in what servers they can connect to. Hence the question whether installing software is OK or not. If it's acceptable, you can just set up a OpenVPN server somewhere in the network.

Comment: sounds very interesting!
I just have to make sure about our organization's rules weather they will accept an openSource technology or not, and also I have to make sure about the bandwidth, will it be as fast as a Cisco ASA 55xx or not

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, the easiest and most robust way to establish an IPsec VPN server is to employ a SOHO firewall. Besides the VPN server you'll get control over services, applications, usage times etc. and UTM features like anti-virus, IPS, application control, for all network hosts.

Cisco, Dell Sonicwall, Watchguard offer models but I'd recommend a Fortinet FortiGate (for instance, a 60D); all cost below $1000. FortiGates handle IPsec traffic with an ASIC in wirespeed, i.e. 1 Gpbs. The client software (FortiClient) is free for FortiGate owners and supports both IPsec VPN and SSL-VPN. It's available for Windows and Mac OS X, but the FortiGate can connect to the embedded IPsec clients on Android and iOS devices as well.

For a limited budget, Fortinet's "all-inclusive" price model is attractive - all features like VPN, routing, anti-virus, IPS, load-balancing etc. are included in the hardware price (except for the signature subscriptions).

Comment: sounds interesting